# Box containing as much given points as possible in a coordinate system

Tags: java, math

I have a question:
It's may a bit more a mathematical question, but in informatical context.

I have a number of *n* points on a coordinate system. (They are randomly placed.)

My problem is, to find a box which has a diameter *d* and (theoretically) infinite length (like a big line) that **contains as much of the *n* points as possible**.

Any idea?

I finally want to write a programm in Java based on the answers, but a already written one is welcome, too  ;)

Comment: What do you mean by "diameter" in the context of a line?

Comment: In addition to @templatetypedef's question - can these points fall on any coordinate? Or will the x and y coordinates be integers?

Comment: The straightforward O(n^3) solution would be to try lines between every pair of points and count how many other points are on that line.

Comment: It's not actually a line, more a box width a height of d following a line. The coordinates are doubles.

Comment: @LouisWasserman The best solution needn't have any two of the points on its center line. Consider four dots placed in a square just close enough together that a line through the center of the square can catch all four of them. I'm thinking in the direction of linear regression, but that can give bad answers in some cases as well.

Comment: @tihox1 You should *definitely* update your question with that information - if that's the case, the question you've asked is totally different from the question you'd like answered!

Comment: Exponential runtime complexity is not acceptable, is it? :P

Comment: @Wintermute: tihox hadn't mentioned the box when I made my suggestion.  If it had _just_ been a line, I think my solution would have been correct.

Comment: @LouisWasserman If it had been a line, with randomly placed dots in R^2, you'd just have to pick any two and put a line through them because the probability that there's one with three is precisely zero. Although I suppose there's a slight chance with floating point imprecision, but then the chance is still low and the results machine-dependent.

Comment: @Stefan Falk: Could you un-delete your RANSAC-answer? I think that might be a good idea. Although the sample cardinality should be more than 2 (maybe even up to 10) to allow averaging.

Comment: If you can formulate this as a math problem, you might try asking mathematicians (e.g. math.stackexchange.com). A way to state the problem (if I understand you correctly) might be: "Suppose I am given an arbitrary set of n points in a coordinate plane and a fixed constant r. What algorithm will find the line L that maximizes the number of points in the given set that are within a distance r from L?" (To use this algorithm for your "box", you would set r = d/2.)